# JetBrains (IntelliJ, PhpStorm, WebStorm ...) private git repository with SSH key

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

My New Web Server need authentication with RSA 2048 key.

I therefore generated a key, I placed the `ir_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files in my home folder `~/.ssh` (Windows 10).

But When I use the cvs comment (for pull or push) I get an error :

[image]

**The Error Log is (with built-in SSH executable) :**

> 15:14:14.657: [MyProject] git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
>   --progress --prune java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to mywebhost.fr:22 at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:791) at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:577) at
>   org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:171) at
>   org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:137) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is
>   closed. at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:92)
>   at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:230)
>   at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:743) ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not
>   match. at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:413)
>   at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:754)
>   at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:469)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

**The Error Log is (with "Settings > Version Control > git > SSH Executable" to "native") :**

> 15:13:50.031: [MyProject] git -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
>   --progress --prune Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct
>   access rights and the repository exists.

**If I use the Git command in terminal the pull or push command works good :**

[image]

**What should I do to use PhpStorm's VCS buttons?**

- I tried to set `Settings > Version Control > git > SSH Executable` to
  "native" : Same problem
- I tried to Install putty utility, run "Pageant" services and import my
  private key : Same problem
- I tried to run `ssh-add` : Same problem

[image]

- I tried to configure the `~/.config` file: Same problem

> Host myHost.fr
>     Hostname myHost.fr
>     User myloginuser
>     IdentityFile C:\Users\username.ssh\id_rsa

My Git version is : **2.10.2.windows.1** (downloaded from https://git-scm.com/download/win)

My OS is Windows 10

---

**[Edit] Solution :**
Thank you to Dmitriy Smirnov, I found the Solution :

In the `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` folder you will find the file `start-ssh-pageant.cmd`.

Before launching it is necessary to create an environment variable:

```
Name: SSH_AUTH_SOCK
Value: C:\Users\username\.ssh\.ssh-pageant-username
```

(I tried with Pagent from Putty, and ssh-agent from Git Bash but it did not work)

Comment: *(for reference purposes)* The same asked on PhpStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ built-in SSH executable does not support strong security keys at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140196

Also, your keys are protected by a passphrase, that is why Native SSH does not work. IDE is not a terminal so cannot handle the prompt for a passphrase issued by the git

As a workaround, you could load the key to a ssh-agent, so executing `git pull` from the command prompt does not prompt you for a passphrase, and use Native SSH.