# Unable to negotiate with __IP_ADDRESS_ port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, rsa, git-clone

While using git clone in PhpStorm, I got an error message:

> Clone failed
> Unable to negotiate with IP ADDRESS port 22: no matching host key type      found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
> Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I then made my own RSA key in and saved it on my computer;
also registered it on the server (by server host) where I wanted to get git clone. I've also downgraded my latest PhpStorm version. As a last resort I have also reset my computer and reinstalled PhpStorm.

But I still have that error message in my PhpStorm event log.

Plus, when I first got PhpStorm, I could easily get clone successfully, but suddenly after days, I've got event log entries like that.

Can I get a solution about this, OTL

Comment: We need to check IDE debug logs to advise. Please contact the support team via Help | Contact Support to investigate this further.

Comment: What is your git version? Since Git 2.33 the openssh that comes with Git deprecated DSA keys by default. Quick solution => downgrade to Git 2.32.

Answer (score 39):

On Linux/Ubuntu I added the following lines to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

I guess it is equivalent (and better) to put the same lines in a separate file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d`.

Comment: If you can't edit the system /etc/ssh version, copy it to ~/.ssh/config to have your personal copy that you can manage yourself. (Also works with Git Bash on WIndows)

Comment: Thanks.  That solved my problem of not being able to ssh into my shared hosting account at HostGator that started happening after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This begs the question, why isn't it enabled by default? Is it insecure?

Comment: Please do not enable the weaker cryptographic algorithms for all hosts. Put the options for example under `Host` like in the other answers here.

Answer (score 21):

Add `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` and `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` attributes.

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

```
Host hostname_of_machine
    HostName hostname_or_ip_address
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/file.pem
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: could you please add example of `hostname_of_machine` and `hostname_or_ip_address`

Comment: hostname_of_machine = stackoverflow, 
hostname_or_ip_address = 151.101.193.69

Answer (score 6):

This is because [OpenSSH have deprecated ssh-rsa](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8).
To enable it, add `-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` to your command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, try this.

1. Follow these commands. You can generate `id_rsa` file and `id_rsa.pub`. Basically, These files can be found on `~/.ssh` directory.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

```
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip
```

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com
```

2. Create a `config` on `~/.ssh` directory and paste these attributes.

```
# GitLab.com
Host gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_com_rsa

# Private GitLab instance
Host gitlab.company.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example_com_rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

- You should change the `Host` and `IdentityFile` accordingly. For example: `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
- Please note these attributes. `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` and `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`

3. Try this command and verify that your SSH key was added correctly.

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com
```

References: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#rsa-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me ,
enter ssh config with this command , `sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config`
and then add follow new two line into your ssh config ,

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

save and exit
login again ssh
if you got this message "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!"
type this command and hit enter , `rm .ssh/known_hosts`
try login again ssh.
my English is bad sorry for inconvinience

Answer (score 0):

Check, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42599720/6309), if using a private key *without* passphrase improves the situation.

Check also `settings>Version Control>git >SSH Executable`: try system instead of "native", and double-check your `%PATH%` (Windows) or `$PATH` (Linux/Mac).

On Windows, I would make sure `C:\Program files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` comes first.

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands:

```bash
apt update
```

```bash
apt install rsh-client
```

Then try this again.

```bash
rslogin -l user hostIP
```